# Store the output of ffprobe into a string

Tags: bash

I know that normally you can do something like var=echo "hello world" | grep hello and var will be equal to "hello world"
However when I'm trying to do "var=ffprobe file.mp3 | grep artist" to store the song's artist into var as a string, it doesn't work.
Any thoughts?

Comment: you're doing `var=$(command)` right? if so, iirc ffprobe outputs in stderr so you have to add `2>&1` at the end of ffprobe command

Comment: `var=echo "hello world" | grep hello` doesn't set `var` to the output of the command. It sets `var` to the word `echo`, then tries to execute `"hello world"` as a command. You're missing the `$()` or backticks around the command whose output should be substituted.

Answer (score 3):

Seems ffprobe, writing to stderr(comment has this mentioned already)
But if you want only artist, you have to use 'w' flag as well.

```bash
> $ ffprobe "Adigo Alladigo.mp3" 2>&1 | grep artist
    artist          : SP.Balu
    album_artist    :
```

```bash
> $ ffprobe "Adigo Alladigo - SenSongsMp3.Co.mp3" 2>&1 | grep -w artist
    artist          : SP.Balu
```

Hope it helps.